# fluend plugin in kuberntes

Tags: kubernetes, charts, fluentd, configmap

I want to install a plugin for fluentd throttle in kuberntes during chart installtion
I found this command: for fluentd

```
$ gem install fluent-plugin-throttle
```

but I am new to  kuberntes and could not found where to add so  it will be installed as part of the chart  deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the official (now deprecated) you can supply `plugins.pluginsList` for the chart to download and install for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick look at the [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/fluentd/values.yaml) of the official **fluentd** helm chart and you will see in line 42 the following section:

```
plugins:
  enabled: false
  pluginsList: []
```

So basically you just need to edit this file by setting `enabled` to `true` and providing your plugins list, so it may look as follows:

```
plugins:
  enabled: true
  pluginsList:
  - fluent-plugin-throttle
```

You can even [upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) your already deployed **fluentd** with such list of additional plugins. You can compare it with [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/9564#issuecomment-443111599) comment about the installation of **grafana** plugins.